# How to prevent SymbolicC constructs from using the semicolon (;) as the separator?

Tags: code-generation

When putting several [SymbolicC](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/SymbolicC/guide/SymbolicC.html) expressions in a list, they will usually be joined together with semicolons in the final generated code:

```
<< SymbolicC`

{CCall["g", 2], CCall["h", 3]} // ToCCodeString
```

```c
g(2);
h(3);
```

This is true when pieces of code are given as strings too:

```
{"a=1", "b=2"} // ToCCodeString
```

```c
a=1;
b=2;
```

But there are a few special construct that don't use the semicolon as separator, e.g. `CBlock`:

```
{CBlock[{"a=1"}], "b=2"} // ToCCodeString
```

```c
{
a=1;
}
b=2;
```

I would like to be able to include bits of code as *strings* and not have them terminated by `;`.  For example, the following behaviour is undesirable:

```
{"{a=1;}", "b=2"} // ToCCodeString
```

```c
{a=1;};
b=2;
```

**How can I prevent semicolons from being added at the end of certain pieces of code?**

Motivation:

- It is just easier to type fixed bits of C code as a string than in terms of SymbolicC.
- When working with C++, it becomes necessary to use strings as many C++ constructs cannot be represented in SymbolicC

Answer (score 7):

To achieve this, we can define a new SymbolicC construct that won't get semicolons at the end.  Let's call it `CInlineCode`.

We will need to provide translation rules for conversions to a string. This is done in terms of `` SymbolicC`GenerateCode `` (which is a slightly lower level version to `ToCCodeString`).

In general, translation rules are attached to `GenerateCode` and need to:

- Translate anything inside the construct by recursively calling `GenerateCode`
- Glue the resulting bits of strings together

We define our own `CInlineCode`:

```
Needs["SymbolicC`"]

GenerateCode[CInlineCode[arg_], opts : OptionsPattern[]] := GenerateCode[arg, opts]
```

Whether a construct uses `;` as a separator is determined by the function `` SymbolicC`Private`IsCExpression ``.  The default is *no semicolon*, so we don't actually need to do this for `CInlineCode`, but for the sake of completeness (and to show how we could force semicolons if we wanted to):

```
SymbolicC`Private`IsCExpression[ _CInlineCode ] := False (* change to True to force semicolon *)
```

Now we can do

```
{CInlineCode["{a=1;}"], "b=2"} // ToCCodeString
```

```c
{a=1;}
b=2;
```

No more semicolon after `}`!

---

Needless to say relying on internal implementation details of a package is fragile, so this method might not work in future versions.

Comment: Admittedly, this is a very basic thing but I hope it'll save someone the trouble of going into the package file and figuring out how it works.  It's also a very basic example of how to create new SymbolicC constructs.